# cs50 PSET4 - filter questions and issues in my code

Tags: c, cs50

Have been working for some time on the PSET4 of CS50, it requires one to create four functions that apply various effects to an input image. grayscale, sepia, reflect, and blur.

When I first finished the code, barely any of it worked when I checked it. Much of it I fixed through essentially mindlessly adding a bunch of variables which for some reason had fixed many of my problems.

Could someone explain why the original code didn't work and achieved mere approximations?

Here is the original and then updated:

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            BYTE avg = round((image[x][y].rgbtBlue + image[x][y].rgbtRed + image[x][y].rgbtGreen) / 3);
            image[x][y].rgbtBlue = avg;
            image[x][y].rgbtRed = avg;
            image[x][y].rgbtGreen = avg;
            }
    }
    return;
    }
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
                BYTE originalRed = image[x][y].rgbtRed;
                BYTE originalGreen = image[x][y].rgbtGreen;
                BYTE originalBlue = image[x][y].rgbtBlue;
    
                image[x][y].rgbtRed = .393 * originalRed + .769 * originalGreen + .189 * originalBlue;
                image[x][y].rgbtGreen = .349 * originalRed + .686 * originalGreen + .168 * originalBlue;
                image[x][y].rgbtBlue = .272 * originalRed + .534 * originalGreen + .131 * originalBlue;
                if (image[x][y].rgbtRed > 255) {
                    image[x][y].rgbtRed = 255;
                }
                if (image[x][y].rgbtGreen > 255) {
                    image[x][y].rgbtGreen = 255;
                }
                if (image[x][y].rgbtBlue > 255) {
                    image[x][y].rgbtBlue = 255;
                }
            }
         }
        return;
    }
```

---

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            int red = image[x][y].rgbtRed;
            int green = image[x][y].rgbtGreen;
            int blue = image[x][y].rgbtBlue;

            int avg = round(((float)red + (float)green + (float)blue) / 3);
            image[x][y].rgbtBlue = avg;
            image[x][y].rgbtRed = avg;
            image[x][y].rgbtGreen = avg;
            }
    }
    return;
}

// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            int originalRed = image[x][y].rgbtRed;
            int originalGreen = image[x][y].rgbtGreen;
            int originalBlue = image[x][y].rgbtBlue;

            int sepiaRed = round(.393 * originalRed + .769 * originalGreen + .189 * originalBlue);
            int sepiaGreen = round(.349 * originalRed + .686 * originalGreen + .168 * originalBlue);
            int sepiaBlue = round(.272 * originalRed + .534 * originalGreen + .131 * originalBlue);

            if (sepiaRed > 255) {
                image[x][y].rgbtRed = 255;
            }
            else{
                image[x][y].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
            }
            if (sepiaGreen > 255) {
                image[x][y].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }
            else{
                image[x][y].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
            }
            if (sepiaBlue > 255) {
                image[x][y].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }
            else{
                image[x][y].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
            }
        }
     }
    return;
}
```

Comment: In this `if (image[x][y].rgbtGreen > 255)` it's too late to check the range after writing to the smaller type, and you corrected this.

Comment: Aside: it could be confusing to use variable `x` for height and `y` for width.

Comment: @WeatherVane The x-y coordinate thing: Yeah - realized that when I started on the Blur function...

Comment: And what do you mean by it being too late?

Comment: The `image[x][y].rgbtGreen` *can't be* `> 255`. It has already been truncated to 8 bits.

Comment: `int avg = round((red + green + blue) / 3.0f);` is how I would fix the average issue.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't just average the R, G, and B values to get a grayscale. For perceptually better results, I would use a colorimetric luminance, such as Y (as in YIQ or YUV): `Y = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B`